# Chrome: Page reload via submitting address line does not invoke HTML5 video

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, html5-video, reload

I have got the following HTML5 video in my markup:

```
<video loop="loop" preload="auto" id="welcome-video" class="full-screen-background">
    <source src="videos/background-video.m4v" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Everything works fine except the page reloading behavior in Chrome. When the page is loaded initially the page is loaded as expected. Also when I click the reload button or hit Cmd + R the page gets reloaded and the video is played fine.

BUT when I click into the address line and hit the enter button again the page is reloaded but the video does not play :-(

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just tried something similar on a page I had lying around, and it worked fine for me. Can you set up a live demo?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It was all due to me using http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/ for my page. Somehow it's Javascript prevented my videos from working even though I spent a lot of time for debugging I could find a solution so I had to keep going without pagePiling :-(